# How to make a SharePoint:FormField required in custom NewForm?

Tags: 2010, column, custom-form, prerequisites

I'm looking for a simple way to make a SharePoint:FormField required.

I want to do it using C# or SharePoint options but not using JQuery or Javascript because I already know how to do it with JS an JQuery. Obviously the "Required='TRUE'" attribute within list column definition is useless, at least for custom forms. Please a way that do not include Using UI will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the field in the list to be required, that would be my first step.

Comment: Yes I did it already :(

Comment: You are creating form first and then making changes to your list after making fields mandatory or non-mandatory. You need to create the form once again after making changes. So that you will see that field as a mandatory.

Comment: Thank you ! I saw your answer a little bit too late. Please don't pay attention to my comment below your answer.

Comment: Ok that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make that column required by going to List Settings and clicking on to the column, and then just clicking option Yes under "Required that this columns contains information". If you are using sharepoint Forms, then I think you need to create again the new form if you are making changes on the list after creating the new form. That changes will get updated only when you create the new form once again. So first we need to define which columns are to be made mandatory and which are to be made non-mandatory. There is immense importance to define list architecture first of all in SharePoint.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to recreate all my custom forms (New and Edit ) if I decided to change one attribute of one of my columns ?